# Socket programming between client in C#.NET and server in C

Tags: c#, c, sockets

Here I would like to ask how to create communication through socket programming between client  (on Windows, using C#.NET) and server (on Ubuntu, using C).
I have done successfully if the server-client both are either C#.NET or C but have no idea to do as I asked.
I have tried to find information in several sites but couldn't find the exact one. 
I appreciate any comments. Thank you.

Here is simple codes on client.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Receiving byte array  
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        Socket senderSock;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn_connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create one SocketPermission for socket access restrictions 
                    SocketPermission permission = new SocketPermission(
                    NetworkAccess.Connect,    // Connection permission 
                    TransportType.Tcp,        // Defines transport types 
                    "",                       // Gets the IP addresses 
                    SocketPermission.AllPorts // All ports 
                    );

                // Ensures the code to have permission to access a Socket 
                permission.Demand();

                // Resolves a host name to an IPHostEntry instance            
                IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("");

                // Gets first IP address associated with a localhost 
                IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];

                // Creates a network endpoint 
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 4510);

                // Create one Socket object to setup Tcp connection 
                senderSock = new Socket(
                    ipAddr.AddressFamily,// Specifies the addressing scheme 
                    SocketType.Stream,   // The type of socket  
                    ProtocolType.Tcp     // Specifies the protocols  
                    );

                senderSock.NoDelay = false;   // Using the Nagle algorithm 

                // Establishes a connection to a remote host 
                senderSock.Connect(ipEndPoint);



            }
            catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString()); }

        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Sending message 
                //<Client Quit> is the sign for end of data 
                string theMessageToSend = text_IP.Text;
                byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(theMessageToSend + "<Client Quit>");

                // Sends data to a connected Socket. 
                int bytesSend = senderSock.Send(msg);


            }
            catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString()); }
        }



    }
}
```

this is the codes in server (in C)

```
include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "sys/socket.h"
#include "sys/types.h"
#include "netinet/in.h"
#include "error.h"
#include "strings.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "arpa/inet.h"

#define ERROR    -1
#define MAX_CLIENTS    
#define MAX_DATA    1024


main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    int sock;
    int new,i;
    int sockaddr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    printf("sockaddr_len");
    int data_len;
    char data[MAX_DATA];
    char temp[MAX_DATA];


    if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == ERROR)
    {
        perror("server socket: ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bzero(&server.sin_zero, 8);

    if((bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sockaddr_len)) == ERROR)
    {
        perror("bind : ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if((listen(sock, MAX_CLIENTS)) == ERROR)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("\nThe TCPServer Waiting for client on port %d\n",ntohs(server.sin_port));
        fflush(stdout);

    while(1) // Better signal handling required
    {
        if((new = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &sockaddr_len)) == ERROR)
        {
            perror("accept");
            exit(-1);
        }

        printf("New Client connected from port no %d and IP %s\n", ntohs(client.sin_port), inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr));

        data_len = 1;


        while(data_len)
        {
            data_len = recv(new, data, MAX_DATA, 0);
            printf("\nRecieved mesg from client: %s", data);

            for( i = 0; data[ i ]; i++)
            {
                /* if(data[i]=='a' || data[i]=='e' || data[i]=='i' ||data[i]=='o' || data[i]=='u' )
                    data[ i ] = toupper( data[ i ] );
                else */
                data[ i ] = data[ i ] ;

            }    

            if(data_len)
            {

                send(new, data, data_len, 0);
                data[data_len] = '\0';
                printf("\nSent mesg to client: %s", data);
            }

        }

        printf("Client disconnected\n");

        close(new);

    }

    close(sock);


}
```

Comment: Is there some reason you doubt *your* socket code in C/C# would work correctly hitting your client/server in C#/C? If so, how on earth can we know the root of that doubt without seeing *code* ?

Comment: sorry, I forget attaching it. I edited and attached the client code.
for the server code, i indeed have an example program but it doesn't work with this client codes.
The client code is working with the server codes in C#.NET though.

Comment: Can you please tell us in which way it does not work? Can you connect to the server? Do you get some error message/exception? In the client code you call GetHostEntry with an empty hostname. Have you used there the hostname of the server while testing?

Comment: I couldn't connect to server..NO response from server.

Answer (score 0):

Socket is universal concept and not specific to any language.
You can go ahead and use the same C Ubuntu Server code and C# Windows Client code.

Few Things you need to take care of are :

- How you bind the server & client and protocol used.
- Firewall settings.

Hope you can kick start with these inputs

**Happy Coding :)**

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I am trying to re-make my codes for server on Windows. Hope it can work soon :D

Comment: Did u try running the C server side code on windows.
try to run server and client on windows.

Answer (score 0):

So I am assuming your clients can at least talk to each other. But it looks like your issue is that you are sending your text in Unicode format from C# and then receiving it as ASCII on the client side. Unless the default isn't ASCII for your 'C' client.

Comment: I changed my codes already from Unicode to ASCII using System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes
my biggest problem is that I don't know how to create the right codes for server in C. I've got some examples and tried to modified it but still doesn't work.

Comment: At the end, I couldn't connect to the server and send the data either.
anyway, thank you for your comments :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Client Code you you call `GetHostEntry` with an empty hostname. This will give you the IP Address of your Client.

You should call `GetHostEntry` with the host name of the server:

```
// Resolves a host name to an IPHostEntry instance            
IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("Server.Host.Name");

// Gets first IP address associated with a localhost 
IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];

// Creates a network endpoint 
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 4510);
```